# DynamoDB table is getting created but can not insert new items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am using the boto DynamoDBV2 interface for a script to create and populate a table in the DynamoDB. My code for it looks something like this -

```
my_table = Table.create(table_name, schema=[HashKey('key', data_type=STRING)], connection = self.connection)
my_table.put_item(data={
         'key': 'somekey',
         'value': value
      })
```

I have created the connection, and when I run it, the table is created properly and I can see it in the AWS console. But I am getting the error "Requested Resource not found" when trying to put values in the table.

I also tried reading table separately and then insert values like this -

```
Table.create(table_name, schema=[HashKey('key', data_type=STRING)], connection = self.connection)
my_table = Table(table_name, self.connection)
my_table.put_item(data={
         'key': 'somekey',
         'value': value
      })
```

but still getting the same error on the second line. What am I missing ?

Comment: can you catch and add the full traceback of the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table will not be immediately ready on creation, you have to wait for it to become active before writing to it.  I found a [Java code sample](http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2LVB1TA774M13/Snippet-Creating-Amazon-DynamoDB-Tables) that illustrates how to do this, but the problem is not language-specific, it applies to any DynamoDB client.

You can see this in the AWS Management Console as the "Status" of the table, to confirm or deny this theory.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you need to wait a little bit after the table is created before inserting items. You can use the `waitFor()` event to find when the table finishes to be created.

Example with AWS Node SDK:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

const createTableParams = {
  // parameters...
}

dynamodb.createTable(createTableParams, (err, data) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err, err.stack);

    const params = {
        TableName: 'MY_TABLE'
    };

    dynamodb.waitFor('tableExists', params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else     insertData();
    });    
});
```